# Setinterval is stop working when tab is idle or working on another tab,

Tags: javascript, setinterval, requestanimationframe

I have created a solution for sessiontimeout popup, to check idle time I am using a setInterval as mentioned below

```
    // Increment the idle time counter every 1 second.
    idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 2000, (@warningShowDelayMinutes * 60), (@sessionTimeout * 60), @warningTimeLeft);

function timerIncrement(warningShowDelay, sessionTimeout) {
        idleTime++;
        console.log("before dialog open idleTime - :" + idleTime);
        if (idleTime >= warningShowDelay && idleTime <= sessionTimeout) {
            var isWarningPopupOpened = $('#session-expire-warning').dialog('isOpen');
            if (!isWarningPopupOpened) {
                $("#session-expire-warning").dialog("open");
                //console.log("before dialog after idleTime -:" + idleTime);
            }
        }
    }
```

but when we move to another tab/ another window, setInterval stops working,
I also tried with requestAnimationFrame but it also stop working after we move to another tab or window as mentioned below.

```
var last = 0;
function timerIncrement(now) {
     if (!last || now - last >= 1000) {
        last = now;
        //createNewObject();
   
        idleTime++;
        console.log("before dialog open idleTime - :" + idleTime);
        if (idleTime >= (@warningShowDelayMinutes * 60) && idleTime <=  (@sessionTimeout * 60)) {
            var isWarningPopupOpened = $('#session-expire-warning').dialog('isOpen');
            if (!isWarningPopupOpened) {
                $("#session-expire-warning").dialog("open");
                console.log("before dialog after idleTime -:" + idleTime);
            }
        }
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(timerIncrement);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(timerIncrement);
```

can anyone help on this to continue the setinetrval or requestAnimationFrame after tab switching ? I am new to javascripts

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [worker-timers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/worker-timers) NPM package to overcome this hurdle. It uses Web worker to prevent the timer(s) being throttled by the browser.

Comment: Hi Gelvo ,Thanks for your reply , but can't use this as it is not reccommoned by client. Thanks

Comment: Well, if your client does not want to use WebWorker and you can't implement your own `setTimer` and/or `setInterval` in WebAssembly - then you're simply out of options and will have to live with the throttling in the browser.

Comment: how to use requestAnimationFrame as a timeinterval any idea ?

Comment: It is throttled in almost the same way - otherwise people would not have bothered to create WebWorker timers ...